# SSH tunneling with Eclipse and RSE plugin

Tags: eclipse, ssh, tunneling

I access my remote machine(say abc2) by first logging into a login server(say abc1) and then logging from there to my remote machine. Both have different passwords. Is there any way to work on such a remote machine in Eclipse using the Remote System Explorer plugin ?